# calling a function on url call in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new to angularjs and require help on calling a function on url call. 
I am directly accessing the query params from url using

http://localhost/index.html#/?defined=true&var1=value1&var2=value2&

```
$location.search()['defined'];
```

now , within my controller I have a function 'caller' which is being called on events like ng-change , ng-model etc. on the html page which works fine

```
angular.module('ngAp').controller
('ngCntrl',function($scope,$http,$location{

    $scope.caller = function() {
       // code logic 
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to call the function 'caller' when I directly access the above url

```
$location.search()['defined'];

if (defined == "true" )
{ //call the caller function.

}
```

I have no idea how can I call the function when i directly call the url. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To call the function simply use `$scope.caller();` Did you mean something else?

Comment: Thanks , it worked , but now I am running into a different problem.I have a call to $http.get() inside the controller which isnt getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the docs for $location - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

It has some events you can use like `$locationChangeStart`. But it's better to bind to this event in `angular.module('ngAp').run(...)`.

```
angular.module('ngAp').run(moduleRun);
function moduleRun ($location, $rootScope) {
  $location.on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, newUrl, oldUrl, newState, oldState) {
    var defined = $location.search()['defined'];
    $rootScope.defined = defined //you can assign it to $rootScope;
    if (defined === "true" ) {
      //call the caller function.
    }
  })
}
```